# how to stop other sites linking non available urls to our site which leads to 404

Tags: backlinks, 404

I check webmastertools for 404's.

I can see other sites linking to my site but with additional characters which makes the link a 404 in my site.

for example

if i have a url like sitename.com/category/product-name.html and other sites read this content from some other source and are listing in their site like

sitename.com/category/product-name.htmlAs

because of such improper link backs(which i did not create in that site) i get a lot of 404's in webmastertools.

how do we prevent this?

Comment: 404's are perfectly normally. If people are linking to pages that don't exist then a 404 is the error to report and is good that your site is returning this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one can stop you from linking to a non-existent page on any website on the Internet, and likewise you cannot stop anyone from linking to a non-existent page on your website.

If it is a "real" website with people to contact, you could try to get in touch with a webmaster to correct what may just be a typo. If it's some kind of spammy/automated/low-quality kind of website, there's not much you can do about those links - this happens for pretty much every website of any noticeable size out there.

However, you can try to redirect those 404's to an real page to reduce the errors, salvage the pagerank from the links, and help any visitors who might follow those links. Although if the links are coming from low-quality sites, they're not giving you much value or visitors anyway, and I wouldn't be too concerned about them showing up in GWT - again, pretty much everyone gets this.